# Change the search everywhere highlight color in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, themes

I recently changed my color scheme in IntelliJ to Monokai Pro (Filter Spectrum), part of the Monokai Pro Theme plugin, and this has caused a lot of highlighted text in the UI to become unreadable due to poor contrast.

When using the search everywhere tool, I ran into an issue where the text being searched is highlighted in a bright yellow color while the text itself remains white, making the highlighted text almost impossible to read. This also seems to happen when searching files in the project directory.

Here are some examples:

[Search Everywhere Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXq3J.png)

[Project Directory Search Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk0Rx.png)

I have searched through the IntelliJ settings myself but the only search and highlighting color settings I've found are for text highlighting inside of the editor.

Is it possible to change either the color of the highlight itself or the color of the highlighted text?

Comment: This color is defined in the theme plug-in, and there is no setting to override it. Please report a bug to the plug-in maintainer.